# dictionary within other dictionary in django template

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates

In a Django template, is there a way to get a value id, `score` and `num_votes` from Data Structure:

```
{
    1: {'score': 0,  'num_votes': 2}, 
    2: {'score': -1, 'num_votes': 1}, 
    3: {'score': 2,  'num_votes': 2}, 
    6: {'score': 1,  'num_votes': 1}, 
    7: {'score': 2,  'num_votes': 2}
}
```

Example:

```
1  0  2 
2 -1  1
```

---

In django template, but throws error:

```
{% scores_for_objects list_status as scores %}
{% for status,value in scores.items %}
{{status}}**{{value.'score'}}
{{value.'num_votes'}}**{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not [how you do it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables).

```
            {{status}}**{{value.score}}{{value.num_votes}}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood your question but try that :

```
{% for key1, dict in my_main_dict.items %}
  {% for sub_key, value in dict.items %}
    {{ key1 }} {{ key2 }} {{ value }} <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```